# Resizing image client side and uploading via AJAX only works sometimes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm having an issue with code to allow a user to submit an image file via a form, resize it client side, upload it via AJAX and PHP to a Wordpress site, and then showing a thumbnail version of the image. The problem is the code only works sometimes and it seems to prefer some files over others. I have one jpeg image that only uploads maybe once out of every 10 attempts and other jpeg images that upload 5 out of 10 times. Also, when an image is uploading and reaches 100%, sometimes the progress bar will go back down to about 85% and then go up to 100% again. I'm thinking this is the cause of my issue, but I haven't been able to figure out how to fix it.

jQuery:

```
$('#myform-fileinput').change(function() { 
    if ($('#myform-fileinput').length) {

        if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {

            var filesToUpload = document.getElementById('myform').files;
            var file = filesToUpload[0];

            var img = document.createElement("img");
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e)
            {
                img.src = e.target.result;

                var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                // Do other manipulations and send via AJAX here
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you considered performing the task server side with imagemagick?  You can also look at using some other options, for instance invoking "inkscape" with exec() from PHP.  I have had some great success with that recently - converting massive pdfs to pngs, reducing the pngs and then converting them back to pdf.  With only a handful of lines.

Comment: I can do the resizing server side, but if I allow users to upload big image files, it will take a long time when they upload from their phones.

Comment: Edit: this code works all the time when using Chrome. When using Firefox, it fails when initially uploading an image and the alert that's supposed to come up during successful completion of the AJAX call comes up before the progress bar gets to 100%. But if I immediately try to upload the same image again, it works. In Safari, it just works sometimes at random. I'm thinking the success handler is sometimes getting called before the upload is complete. Any ideas on why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue, which turned out to be very simple. In the code, instead of doing

```
reader.onload = function(e)
        {
            img.src = e.target.result;

            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            // Do other manipulations and send via AJAX here
        }
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

I needed to do

```
reader.onload = function(e)
        {
            image.onload = function () {
               var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
               var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
               ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
               // Do other manipulations and send via AJAX here
            }

            image.src = e.target.result;
        }
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

I just needed to give time for the image data to load prior to manipulating it.